# How can I get a output from a powershell function into a output file for example txt?

Tags: wpf, powershell

I have made a create function in windows powershell:

```
function create(){
param(
$searchBase = "OU=Customers,DC=test,DC=nl",
$NewOUs = @(Import-csv -Path $txt_csv.Text -Delimiter ";"),
[switch]$ProtectOU
)

$Protect = $true
If ($ProtectOU){$Protect = $true}

<# ------- CREATE OU ------- #>
foreach ($NewOU in $NewOUs) {
    try {
        New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name $NewOU.company -Description $NewOU.description -Path $searchBase -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion $Protect
        }
    catch {
        Write-Host "OU already exists"
        }
}

$UserList = Import-Csv -Path $txt_csv.Text -Delimiter ";"

<# ------- CREATE USERS ------- #>
foreach ($User in $UserList) {

    $OU = $User.path
    $UPN = $User.UPN
    $Password = $User.password 
    $Detailedname = $User.firstname + " " + $User.Lastname 
    $UserFirstname = $User.Firstname 
    $FirstLetterFirstname = $UserFirstname.substring(0,1) 
    $SAM =  $User.UPN
    $Company = $User.company
    $Description = $User.description
    $AccountExpirationDate = $User.accountexpirationdate

    $params = @{ 'Name'=$Detailedname;
                 'SamAccountName'=$SAM;
                 'UserPrincipalName'=$UPN+'@test.nl';
                 'DisplayName'=$Detailedname;
                 'GivenName'=$UserFirstname;
                 'Surname'=$User.Lastname;
                 'AccountPassword'=(ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force);
                 'Enabled'=$True;
                 'PasswordNeverExpires'=$True;
                 'Path'=$OU;
                 'Company'=$Company;
                 'Description'=$Description;
                 'AccountExpirationDate'=$AccountExpirationDate
                 'HomeDrive' = "H:"
                 'HomeDirectory' = "\\home\userdata$\$SAM"
                 'ProfilePath'="\\dc-test\User Profiles$\$SAM"                 
                }

    New-ADUser @params
}
```

I want this create function as a output file for example in a txt.

This is my wpf button object:

```
$button_add.Add_Click({create})
```

When I click on the button the output must generated a output file. I already tried a lot of solutions such ass:

Create | out-file but I don't get the information I want:

source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file

Is it possible to do this?

Kind regards

Comment: but what output do you desire? give an example, perhaps?

Comment: For example the data what is created and if it's successfully created or failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to do the following:

```
"processing New-ADUser with $params" | Out-File log.txt -Append
try {
  New-ADUser @params
  "Created $UPN" | Out-File log.txt -Append
}
catch {
  $_ | Out-File log.txt -Append
}
```

or you could just pass the output of New-ADUser to the Out-File:

```
New-ADUser @params -PassThru | Out-File log.txt -Append
```

Comment: No problems, glad I could help!